# Adding a filter to the Project Explorer in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I want to add a new filter to the Project Explorer, to hide from the user some projects that are created automatically in an Eclipse RCP Application.

So far I've found two extension points:

**org.eclipse.ui.ide.resourceFilters**

Allows me to filter Navigation

**org.eclipse.jdt.ui.javaElementFilters**

Allows me to filter the Java Viewers

I expect there is a similar extension point for the Project Explorer, but so far I haven't had any luck getting it.

I tried importing org.eclipse.ui.navigator and org.eclipse.ui.navigator.resources but I could not find any interesting looking extension point either

I am using Eclipse 3.3.2 as the basis for this RCP Application

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the right set of extension points.  It is more of a pain that I expected, because the Project Explorer is a specialization of the common navigator.

This is a two-step process:

- extend org.eclipse.ui.navigator.navigatorContent

  - Add a common filter to this extension point.
  - Set a name and id to the filter
  - Implement the filter viewer with the desired logic
- extend org.eclipse.ui.navigator.viewer

  - Add a viewerContentBinding
  - Set the content id to org.eclipse.ui.navigator.ProjectExplorer
  - Add two includes
  - In the first include add a patter that matches the id of the common filter
  - In the second include add the id org.eclipse.ui.navigator.resourceContent

And then, the filter is associated to the common Project Explorer

Comment: @Mario: very interesting; thank you for the answer, although you could detailed it a little bit more;). +1

Answer (score 11):

There you go:

```
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.navigator.navigatorContent">
    <commonFilter
        description="Hides *.pj resources"
        id="com.xyz.commonFilter.hidePj"
        name="*.pj resources"
        activeByDefault="true">
        <filterExpression>
            <and>
                <adapt type="org.eclipse.core.resources.IResource">
                    <test property="org.eclipse.core.resources.name" value="*.pj"/>
                </adapt>
            </and>
        </filterExpression>
    </commonFilter>
</extension>
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.navigator.viewer">
    <viewerContentBinding
          viewerId="org.eclipse.ui.navigator.ProjectExplorer">
          <includes>
            <contentExtension pattern="com.xyz.commonFilter.hidePj"/> 
          </includes>
    </viewerContentBinding>
</extension>
```

Don't forget to import **org.eclipse.ui.navigator** package

Comment: Worked perfectly for me and nice that you don't need to create a single class. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Filters... for the *Project* Explorer view?

There are some long standing bugs on that:

- [bug 226046: `CommonNavigator`, add "Name filter patterns" freetext filter](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=226046) (2008)
- [bug 1970: initially same request from the Navigation View](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=1970) (... 2001!)

That may requiere some specific development (as suggested in [this thread](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.platform/msg76669.html))

> you could probably accomplish this by creating a class that extends `ViewFilter` and associating your class with the project explorer.

(Note: FilterViewer were [broken in Eclipse3.3.1](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.platform/msg72895.html), some using 3.3.2 here is a good idea)

Comment: This comment gave a hint.  Indeed, it is done by extending ViewFilter.  The tricky part was getting the right extension point combination to register it to the project explorer.