# Show/hide files in eclipse project explorer depending on requirements

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I am creating an eclipse application which have a switch under menu windwos-preferences-> on/off. Depending on status of this switch I want to update the content of project-explorer i.e. when switch is ON show all files with extension .on and if switch is OFF show all file with extension .off (hide .on and .off files depending on switch selected). How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the Common Navigator Framework to add such functionality to a Navigator View (= views like Project Explorer, Package Explorer, Resource Navigator etc.).

See this question for details:
[Adding a filter to the Project Explorer in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2396297/adding-a-filter-to-the-project-explorer-in-eclipse)