# Eclipse : How to hide a file from Project Explorer?

Tags: c++, eclipse, macos, ide

I'm using the Eclipse IDE for C/C++ running on an iMac, OS X Yosemite.

In my C++ project, I want to hide certain files from the Project Explorer, YET they still be included in the project. I'm trying to run a series of tests for an empirical study I'm doing. Files I'm trying to hide are for test purposes and as such I don't want the participants to be able to see the contents of my test files.

I found the following StackOverflow thread, which does exactly what I want, except for the fact that when I do it, Eclipse excludes the files from compiling.

[Eclipse: how to hide custom files in Project Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6137848/eclipse-how-to-hide-custom-files-in-project-explorer)

How can I merely hide the files without excluding from compiling?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are they headers or sources? Headers can be excluded from view by storing them outside the project root directory yet can still be accessed easily enough with a `#include`

Comment: Both headers and sources.

Answer (score 0):

W.r.t Project Explorer/Navigator view its not possible to merely hide the custom resources based on name patters.

Refer this post for more info : https://stackoverflow.com/a/2396496/1391924

However note that: In C/C++ Projects view you can hide resources based on your own file name patterns.
Refer [this help](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.cdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Fcdt_t_prvw_hide_files.htm).

Comment: This doesn't work, when you do this Eclipse doesn't compile those files.